# swiping image using collectionview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview

I have some images showing on collection view cell. I am swiping it horizontally. I want the next or the previous image to be shown, by swiping it to right or left but it is swiping like the image attached.

#### My image:

[image: My image]

In this image, two images are there.

How to do it so that by swiping one image will come one after another without not more than one image at a time on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what you're asking.  You want only 1 photo to show up, and take up the whole screen, and when you swipe it goes to the next image and snaps it into place?  This would just be as simple as:

1. Making sure your UICollectionViewCell width is the same as the collection view's width.
2. Enabling paging on the collection view. If you are using Storyboard just select your UICollectionView and check the checkbox labeled "Paging Enabled".  To do it programmatically you can just set `collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true`.